# .val() func returns undefined but no copied id

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a basic calculator using asp.net and jquery. I get to the JQuery function by clicking my Calculate button. I want to use myInt to do other things based on what value I get out of it. But myInt always returns undefined or an empty string.

I see that other people have the same problem here on SO. Most solutions say that the OP has duplicated an id somewhere. I've checked and checked and can't find that I've done that. What other problem could I be having?

```html
<form id="calculator" asp-action="CalcEvens">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-center"></div>

      <div class="form-group">
           <label asp-for="myInt" class="control-label">Enter a numba</label>          
           <input asp-for="myInt" class="form-control" min="1" max="999" required="required" type="number" />
           <span asp-validation-for="myInt" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" />
      </div>
</form>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myInt = $("#myInt").value;

        $('#Calculate').on('click', function () {
            console.log(myInt);
        });
    });
```

I need whatever is input into the myInt textbox to be printed to the console. I keep getting "undefined" instead.

Comment: 1st: use `.val()` not `.value` `var myInt = $("#myInt").val();`.. 2nd: to get a value on click use the `var myInt=..... ` line inside the click not outside it .. The problem is when you trying to get the `myInt` you got it onload so it will read undefined or empty but it'll not catch the new value.. Also you don't have an id `myInt` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `val()` not `.value`

```
var myInt = $("#myInt").val();
```

and to get a value on click use the `var myInt=.....` line inside the click method not outside it.

```
$('#Calculate').on('click', function () { 
    var myInt = $("#myInt").val();
    console.log(myInt);
});
```

you got it onload when you trying to get the myInt value so it will read undefined or empty but it'll not catch the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any input with id="myInt" in your html code